# Vague memory of a book series about three particular winged beast riders saving their world from an evil lord and his army

Tags: story-identification, novel

So basically, in this books series, there are three main characters. The story is set in some type of fantasy medieval period. They all rode some type of huge beast. One was a mountain lion with wings, another was a wolf with wings and the third was a bird I think. Two of the riders were boys and one was a girl. I remember a small bit of the title was chronicle of (rest of the title name) The plot of this series is that all three riders make a bond with these beasts during a period in which a evil force is conquering the world and so they band up together to fight against it. The reason why I'm remembering this series so vividly but I can't remember the title is because I read it when I was ten and its was the first book that was so graphic and violent (which my ten year old self loved so much) But the plot and character writing was so good. If you know anything, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year/s did you read these books, and when do you think they might've been published?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 6):

[The Chronicles of Avantia](https://www.goodreads.com/series/89149-the-chronicles-of-avantia) by Adam Blade.

[image: Chronicles of Avantia]

> At the age of seven, Tanner's father was killed in front of him by the evil warlord Derthsin. But his father's death was not in vain and Derthsin was carried away to his doom by a good Beast, Firepos the Flame Bird. Now, eight years later, another evil army is wreaking havoc across Avantia. But Tanner has been training with Firepos, waiting to avenge his father's death. There is something familiar about this new menace, who rides with a Beast of his own. The evil army is after the pieces of the Mask of Death--which allows whoever wears it to control all Beasts. Tanner sets off on a journey to stop them. Along the way, he encouters twins Gwen and Geffen, who hold the map to finding the remaining pieces.

Tanner rides the flame bird *Firepos* while Gwen rides the wolf *Gulkien*:

> The creature was a wolf as big as Firepos. His lean body was covered with shaggy gray fur and his sleek head thrust into the wind. He gazed keenly ahead with piercing eyes. Behind powerful shoulders grew leathery wings, beating the air with slow, languid strokes. Four crouched legs ending in paws with ragged black claws hung in the air beneath him. And on his back, riding with confidence and grace, was Gwen.

I only have the first book, and in that *Geffen* doesn't ride anything as he spends most of the book as a captive. Possibly the winged lion appears in the later books of the series. I note the cover of the third book shows a lion, though not a winged lion:

[image: Call to War]